# Accidently Moved Camera, Get Position Back?

Tags: camera, scene

I accidentally moved my camera using "align to View", which I thought was just for the viewport.

Is there a way to get my camera back to where it was? I'm doing progress shots, so it's essential.

I'm too far out from undo to get it back, and I don't want to risk losing the work I did.

— K

Comment: There is no easy way to do this as far as I am aware, and it might not even be possible. Have you saved versions of your project? It is highly recommended that users save different versions of their project so that they can revert certain things back to a previous version. Also, in future use several cameras. have "Progress" camera and a "Preview" camera.